# Best possible way to Bitwise backwards

Tags: c#

I figured out how to pack my bits being a ushort 16bits, my enums are 1 - 13 so they should all fit. Problem is I know I can unpack in a faster fashion then what I was doing and quite shamefully I didn't want to post my horrid code. Any insight would be appreciative. My Push isn't a string it pushes to a byte array so string would be broken down into individual bytes. My ushort is broken down into 2 bytes a float is broken down into 4 bytes etc etc. Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish.. [image]

**Revised Code Statements 11/27/2018 11:47pm**

**Enums.cs**

```
public enum PacketFlags
{
    None = 0x1,
    Nat = 0x2,
    Hb = 0x4,
    Dat = 0x8,
    Dscvr = 0x16,
    Status = 0x20,
    Conn = 0x40,
    Finn = 0x80,
    ReliableOrdered = 0x100,
    Sequenced = 0x200, 
    NotFragged = 0x400,
    Frag = 0x800,
    Fragout = 0x1000,
}
```

**Methods In Question**

```
    public void WriteHeader()
    {
        Count = Ptr;
        var flag = Fragmented | Proto | Flag;
        var field = (ushort)flag;
        Ptr = 0;
        Push(field);
        Push(_id);
    }

    public void ReadHeader()
    {
        Ptr = 0;

        var header = PullUShort();
        var flags = (PacketFlags)header;
        SetFlag(flags);
        SetProto(flags);
        SetFrag(flags);
        _id = PullUShort();
    }

    private void SetFlag(PacketFlags flags)
    {
        //Set Flag
        if((flags & PacketFlags.None) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.None;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Nat) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Nat;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Hb) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Hb;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Dat) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Dat;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Dscvr) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Dscvr;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Status) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Status;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Conn) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Conn;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Finn) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Finn;
        }
    }

    private void SetProto(PacketFlags flags)
    {
        if ((flags & PacketFlags.ReliableOrdered) != 0)
        {
            Proto = PacketFlags.ReliableOrdered;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Sequenced) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Sequenced;
        }
    }

    private void SetFrag(PacketFlags flags)
    {
        if ((flags & PacketFlags.NotFragged) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.NotFragged;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Frag) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Frag;
        }

        if ((flags & PacketFlags.Fragout) != 0)
        {
            Flag = PacketFlags.Fragout;
        }
    }
```

Please note I am on .Net 3.5 and this is for a networking solution. Enum.HasValue uses reflection if the application is processing 40k + packets a second and running that method compaired to a bitwise operation its slow. I am not looking for easy I would like performance.

Comment: Why aren't your flags using powers of two?  This seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I don't think they will fit in the bit field being a ushort, trying to keep the packet size as small as possible. So 16 bits 1 being set or 0 not set should still work.

Comment: If you can fit them this way, you can fit them using powers of two.  You're using powers of two already, just indirectly.  `1 << x` is always a power of two.  Also, enums can be `ushort`-based.

Comment: So for instance if bit 4 is set that would represent PacketFlags Dat then in the same field if 10 is set then that's a Sequence packet then same field bit 11 is set all the rest of the bits are 0. Cant just do the power of two on it and call it good.

Comment: okay ill change that to a power of 2 good to know thank you I just thought each bit would be represented by 0 - 16 changing above code now

Comment: Please review my answer to help you get started.  I will return tomorrow to respond to any feedback you might have.  Right now you're trying to specify your flags by their position.  Instead, specify them by their *value*.

Comment: Are you sure your `WriteHeader()` method is already writing a correct bits? I'm not quite sure why you're performing bit shift in there.

Comment: I just added all the code to the body I cannot push the bits how your suggesting as I am not pushing a string. My packet is a byte array.

Comment: No one suggested you push a string.  I'm not sure where that came from.

Comment: okay cool still fixing things up but I pushed everything im trying to accomplish out there. working on the fix you provided pretty cool to learn something new thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to specify your flags using bit positions.  Its easier if you just use the values at those bits.

```
[Flags]
public enum PacketFlags : ushort
{
    None   = 0x01,  // this is the same as 1 << 1 = 1
    Nat    = 0x02,  // this is the same as 1 << 2 = 2
    Hb     = 0x04,  // this is the same as 1 << 3 = 4
    Dat    = 0x08,
    Dscvr  = 0x10,
    Status = 0x20,  // this is the same as 1 << 6 = 32
    Conn   = 0x40,
    Finn   = 0x80,
}
```

First, 'none' is typically assigned zero, but that aside, let's assume your flags will always have a bit set, even if no flags are set.

Two, I specified the flag values in hexadecimal, but this isn't necessary.  You can use simple base-10 numbers if you prefer.

Three, all the [`[Flags]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) does is change what happens when you format your enum to a string.  Go ahead and try it.  OR some flags together, then call `.ToString()` on it.  Then remove the attribute, and notice the difference.  It's handy, but doesn't do anything terribly important.

Now, to your question:

Packing is as simple as bitwise-ORing them together:

```
var flag = PacketFlags.Nat | PacketFlags.Hb;
```

You can now cast this to a `ushort`, when you want the number representation of your flags:

```
var imaNumber = (ushort)flag;  // equals 0x06.
```

You can see the `[Flags`] attribute in action:

```
var inEnglish = flag.ToString(); // contains: "Nat, Hb"
```

Unpacking is as simple as casting the `ushort` value to `PacketFlags`:

```
var unpacked = (PacketFlags)imaNumber;
```

You can then check if a particular flag is set using [Enum.HasFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.7.2).

This answer is meant to get you started in the right direction.  I can amend it as necessary in response to feedback.  See where you can take it first.

Comment: your only comparing the PacketFlags these flags only represent 0 - 8 of my bitfield. I would like to do something like this. ushort field = Fragmented | Proto | Flag;

Comment: You should combine them into the same enum.

Comment: Shit okay i have to refactor my whole solution, I understand what you are saying now

Comment: I am on .Net 3.5 Enum.HasValue is not part of the versioning. Also I looked at the Method itself and noticed that it uses reflection if im running 40k packets plus through this networking solution it will be slower then manually doing a bitwise operation. Could you revise the answer to reflect a manual shift?